# Converting facial images to DG2 format - epassport

Tags: image, jpeg, public, fingerprint, der

I am currently working on the public sector project which requires converting facial images and finger images into the DG2 and DG3 formats.

I dont have much help and I am finding it very difficult to understand how to go about it. I have been looking at CBEFF, ANS.1 DER formats but couldnt figure out how to convert the facial images into those formats.

Is there any API to facilitate conversion of Facial image to DG1, fingerprint to DG3 and so on?

I am having problems in understanding how to go about doing this. Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Biometric images such as facial (DG2), fingerprint (DG3), and iris (DG4) can be encoded in JPEG (JFIF) or JPEG2000 (JP2) format. You just need to figure out how to encapsulate these images in their respective Data Groups.

Encoding of each Data Groups are specified in ***Doc 9303 Machine Readable Travel Documents Part 1 Volume 2***. But I think this specification is not free though.